# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier | Trying to import a module but I get this error

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning how to make a javascript game. I am using the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EMxBkqC4z0&t=319s

When I try to import the paddle.js file, the console outputs game.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Note that I am a beginner in JavaScript.

I changed the file path to "paddle" and the full file path "Desktop/JS-Game/paddle.js".

I also double checked all my code in paddle.js.

game.js

```
import Paddle from 'paddle';

let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

ctx.clearRect(0 ,0 , 800, 600);

let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

paddle.draw(ctx);
```

paddle.js

```
export default class Paddle {

    constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {

        this.width = 150;
        this.height= 20;

        this.position = {

            x: gameWidth / 2 - this.width / 2,

            y: gameHeight - this.height - 10
        };
    }

    draw(ctx) {

        ctx.fillStyle = '#FF2'

        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

I was expecting the rectangle to draw onto the canvas but nothing was drawn.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:node.js]? Looks very much like a browser application to me.

Comment: I wasn't sure if node.js was used in this as i had to download it to debug this.

Comment: How did you use node.js to debug something? What exactly were you doing with these files when you got the error?

Comment: If the paddle.js file is in the same folder as game.js, you'd import it like `import Paddle from './paddle'` assuming this is ES6

Comment: i tried to do ./paddle but that also didn't work. I used Visual Studio Code to debug and I had to use node.js to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Check the files URL, are both files in the same level?

If you are editing your code, try clear the browser cache..

Comment: i did check and they are in the same folder. I also cleared the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all of these files are at the root of the current working directory try to import paddle.js as follows.

import Paddle from '/paddle';

or else
import Paddle from '/put the path to paddle.js file here/paddle';

Comment: I don't think the path of paddle is the problem. I'm pretty sure that the error that the console refers to has something to do with the 'import Paddle' part.